# Active State not working in Bootstrap Menu in a single header file

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

My bootstrap navigations focus (highlight) is not changing when I click on other links. No matter what link I go to, the highlight remains on the Menu link.

Every solution I've read says to manually set the active state on the navbar on each page. However, in my case I have one "header.php" which includes the Bootstrap navbar, as an include on every page. So there is, in effect, only one navbar, many pages.
I appreciate any help as I'm new to Bootstrap and JS, thanks.

```
<!-- language: php -->
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color: #041E42;" ><i class="fas fa-globe" style="color:white"></i>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">I P S</a><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <!--if user is logged out: home/menu button inactive -->
    <?php    
    if (isset($_SESSION['userID'])){ 
        echo '<li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="menu.php">Menu <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>';


    }else{
        echo '';  
    }
    ?>
      <li class="nav-item" >
        <a class="nav-link" href="register.php">Register</a>
      </li>

        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Help
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">F.A.Q.</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Online Documentation</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>
      </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">GitHub</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery :

`Add below script under the jQuery CDN link.`

```js
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item').each(function () {
        let pathname = window.location.pathname;
        let link     = '/'+$(this).find('.nav-link').attr('href');

        if( pathname === link ) {
          $(this).addClass('active');
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: So i am expecting a up vote as write/correct answer